# Is there a list of English words where some of their letters can be replaceed with Greek letters?

Tags: word-usage, speech, greek

Is there a list of English words where some of their letters can be replaceed with Greek letters?

for example the word `Archive` can be written as `arXve`, where `X` is the Greek letter `chi`.

Comment: You mean whether there are any English words that happen to contain a sequence of letters that is identical to the Anglicised names of the letters of the Greek alphabet? Yes, of course. Like _αbet_ (alphabet), _aνone_ (anyone), _δ_ (delta), _τtology_ (tautology), _πck_ (pick), etc. There are probably several hundred such words, if not thousands.

Comment: Replacing `Archive ` with `arXve ` is not, as you describe it, replacing some letters with Greek letters. This is English words containing English spellings of Greek letters. The Greek letter `Χ` is **spelled** `CHI` in English, but has respresented for about 2000 years a sound English doesn't have. Earlier in Greek it represented an aspirated `K` sound. Neither of these are present in the English word _archive_, (though some speakers do pronounce that with an aspirated `K` for `CH`). If you have a wordlist and a list of English spellings of Greek letters, a simple fgrep search will do the job

Comment: Well, there are 24 Greek letters, and most have equivalent Roman letters, such that one could do a direct substitution for maybe half the words in the English language.  Would be kind of a meaningless exercise, but you could do it.

Answer (score 2):

"Xmas" is the only word I know of, where a Greek symbol can replace some (but not all) English letters and still be understood by the majority of readers. Something like "arXve" would not be correctly decoded by most people.

I am familiar with many entire English words that have been abbreviated by Greek letters in the areas of math and science. Some are fairly standard (δ for change, Ω for Ohms), some depend upon the context (Σ for summation in math, Σ for Saviour in theology), and some are confusing because they can mean many different things to different people, and usage has changed over time (λ can be used for a wavelength, a light polypeptide chain, the name of a bacteriophage. λ was previously used to symbolize microliter, but has largely been replaced by µL).

Answer (score 0):

There are some English **words** that can be replaced by Greek **symbols** *(letters)*:

for example:  Pi

I don't know of any English words containing mixed English/Greek alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical engineers will regularly use the letter 'u' as the greek letter 'μ' (mu) to replace 'micro' as in: uOhm (microohm) or uA (microampere).

Comment: Interesting... that's kind of the opposite phenomenon.